# ¿Cómo listar país y ciudad correspondiente a un usuario con Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html5, ajax

Tengo una tabla `(Datatables)` con un boton editar, al dar click en dicho boton paso los valores a un id `$('#nombre').val(data[1]);` para que me los 'pinte' en el formulario, el problema es que este usuario tiene un país y una ciudad y si realizo lo siguiente:

```
$('#pais').append('<option value="'+ data[3]+'" selected="selected">' + data[4] + '</option>');
```

```
$('#ciudad').append('<option value="'+ data[5]+'" selected="selected">' + data[6] + '</option>');
```

Se me pintan los datos `(pais Y ciudad)` de manera correcta...

**EL PROBLEMA**

Es que necesito que aparte de mostrar el pais y la ciudad del usuario, tambien me liste los paises y ciudades por si depronto el usuario no pertenecia a ese pais sino que era de otro.

Agradeceria grandamente el interes ya que he intentando varias formas pero no he podido...

**CODIGO**

> /* MUESTRO LOS DATOS EN FORMULARIO PARA EDITAR EMPLEADO */

```
$('#db_usuario tbody').on('click','#editar',function()
    {   
        var data =  db_usuarios.row( $(this).parents(' tr ') ).data();
        var pais = $.trim(data[3]);         

        $('#cedula_usuario').val(data[1]);
        $('#nombre').val(data[1]);
        $('#apellido').val(data[2]);

        $("#pais").empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < paises.length; i++)
        {
            var pais_id_comparativo = paises[i]pais_id;

            if(pais_id_comparativo == pais)
            {
                $("#pais").append(
                '<option value="'+ pais_id_comparativo +'" selected="selected">' + data[4] + '</option>');
            }
            else
            {
                $("#pais").append($('<option>',
                {
                    value: pais_id_comparativo,
                    text: paises[i].pais_descripcion,
                }));
            }     
}
```

> /* LISTO PAISES */

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'listar_pais',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function(respuesta) 
{
    try
    {
        var resultado = respuesta;
        paises = resultado;     

        for(var i = resultado.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            $('#pais').append('<option value="'+ resultado[i].pais_id +'">' + resultado[i].pais_descripcion + '</option>');
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.info(e);
    }       
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
```

La idea es la sgte:

```
cedula: 13456789 // esto es un input="text"
Nombre: Pepito  // esto es un input="text"
Apellido: Perez // esto es un input="text"
Pais: CHILE // esto es un select
ciudad: SANTIAGO DE CHILE // esto es un select
```

Resulta que Pepito no es de `CHILE` sino de `ARGENTINA`

Entonces donde dice `pais` deberia de ser asi:

```
pais: CHILE //este es el pais que corresponde a ese usuario
      ARGENTINA
      COLOMBIA
      PERU
      ETC.
```

De igual manera con las ciudades:

```
ciudad: SANTIAGO DE CHILE //esta es la ciudad que pertenece al usuario y a ese pais
        VALPARAISO
        LA SERENA
ETC. (CIUDADES QUE CORRESPONDAN A ESE PAIS)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema en sí? ¿No te muestra los países? ¿Obtienes un error?

Comment: El problema realmente esque no se como listar todos los paises y ciudad y asi mismo seleccionar el pais y la ciudad correspondiente a un usuario...voy a editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El procedimiento es sencillo:

1. Obtener los países y las ciudades.
2. Iterarlas y añadirlas a los desplegables.
3. Seleccionar el país y la ciudad del usuario.

En el punto tres, el país y la ciudad del usuario ya los hemos recuperado:

```
var paisUsuario = $.trim(data[3]); // país actual
var ciudadUsuario = $.trim(data[4]); // ciudad actual
```

Se supone que ambas variables representan **los ids** del país y de la ciudad. Esto te permitirá seleccionar de los desplegables por medio de dichos ids:

```
$('#pais').val(paisUsuario);
$('#ciudad').val(ciudadUsuario);
```

**Ejemplo**

```
$('#db_usuario tbody').on('click', '#editar', function () {
  var data = db_usuarios.row($(this).parents(' tr ')).data();
  var paisUsuario = $.trim(data[3]); // país actual
  var ciudadUsuario = $.trim(data[4]); // ciudad actual

  $('#cedula_usuario').val(data[1]);
  $('#nombre').val(data[1]);
  $('#apellido').val(data[2]);
  $("#pais").empty(); // limpia selects pais y ciudad
  $('#ciudad').empty();

  // obtiene los países, los itera y los añade al select pais
  getPaises()
    .done(function (paises)) {
      paises.forEach(function (pais) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = pais.id_comparativo;
        option.textContent = pais.nombre; // cambiar por la columna del nombre
        $('#pais').append(option);
      });

      // luego de añadir los paises al select, selecciona el del usuario
      $('#pais').val(paisUsuario);
    });

  // obtiene las ciudades, los itera y los añade al select ciudad
  getCiudades()
    .done(function (ciudades) {
      ciudades.forEach(function (ciudad) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = ciudad.id_comparativo;
        option.textContent = ciudad.nombre; // cambiar por la columna del nombre
        $('#ciudad').append(option);
      });

      // luego de añadir las ciudades al select, selecciona la del usuario
      $('#ciudad').val(ciudadUsuario);
    });
});

function getPaises() {
  return $.ajax({ url: 'listar_pais', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', });
}

function getCiudades() {
  return $.ajax({ url: 'listar_ciudades', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', });
}
```

Comment: Hola @Gustavo Garcia que pena contigo, como funciona el metodo getPaises() o getCiudades? ahi se estan trayendo lo datos? de que manera?

Comment: Es simple y llanamente una petición AJAX que ya estás haciendo: `$.ajax({ url: 'listar_pais', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', })`. Quise que se sobreentienda que las funciones `getPaises` y `getCiudades` **retornan** peticiones AJAX como las q haces.

Comment: @Daniel He actualizadi mi respuesta para mostrarte esa parte.

Comment: Hola @Gustavo García, la funcion getCiudades no tendria que recibir un parametro? ps te lo digo porque ya probe el codigo y me funciona pero unicamente con los paise pero con las ciudades no, y si hago un console.log(ciudades);  y miro en la consola no me trae ninguna dato, te agradezco la ayuda, Saludos

Comment: Tienes que analizar @Daniel, piensa en la causa. ¿No será que `listar_ciudades` debe recibir el id del país? Entonces hazlo; es tu código y debes saber más que nadie cómo funciona.